# removing underline from a link inline.

Tags: asp.net, css

hI am having some trouble with this asp.net template.  I tried `Text-decoration: none` but it didn't work.

```
<telerik:RadListView ID="NewsList" ItemPlaceholderID="ItemsContainer" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false">
    <LayoutTemplate>
      <ul>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemsContainer" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <li style="list-style-type:none;"  data-sf-provider='<%# Eval("Provider.Name")%>'  data-sf-id='<%# Eval("Id")%>' data-sf-type="Telerik.Sitefinity.News.Model.NewsItem">
            <h2 style="font: 13px Verdana; color:black; text-decoration:none;">
                <sf:DetailsViewHyperLink TextDataField="Title" ToolTipDataField="Description" data-sf-field="Title" data-sf-ftype="ShortText" runat="server" />
            </h2>
        <span style="font:8px Verdana" >
            <sf:FieldListView ID="summary" runat="server" Text="{0}" Properties="Summary" WrapperTagName="div"  EditableFieldType="ShortText"/> 
        </span>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListView>
<sf:Pager id="pager" runat="server"></sf:Pager>
```

Both the color of the link, and the Underline are still staying.  how can i change that?

this is the result:
[image]

Comment: Is the developer tool shows that CSS rule applied to that `li`? If not can you share that rendered HTML?

Comment: yes, if i inspect the element, i can toggle the elements on and off but doesn't actually change the output

Comment: In any case, `text-decoration:none` only applies to links not the parent `h2`. So you would need to apply it to the `<sf:DetailsViewHyperLink etc/>`

Comment: Seems like the hyperlink is rendered with overridden style. try applying the style to `sf:DetailsViewHyperLink ` with `CssClass` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your H2 a class name. lets say "link_holder". then in your CSS try something like

```
h2.link_holder a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Also, can you give the sf:DetailsViewHyperLink a CssClass?